# Hard disk- CHS and total sector computation

Tags: hard-drive

My disk info program (gparted on Linux) gives me the following information:

```
Total Sectors: 625142448
Cylinders: 38913
Heads: 255
Sectors/Track: 63
```

The computation `Cylinders * Heads * Sectors/Track` gives me `625137345` which is less than the total sectors reported by the program.

My question is, how do I understand what is happening? I realize that outer cylinders have more sectors/track but I believe that all that information is actually hidden from the end-user and disk controller manages it.

Alternatively put, my question is, if I want to access the last sector, what CHS value would let me do that?

EDIT: Some commenters have (rightly?) wondered why I care about LBA mode. I am writing an MBR.

Would I be right in expecting all modern devices to have LBA access? i.e. int 0x13 [ax=0x42] calls to return cx=0x1?

Comment: 1) Can you even still use CHS to access anything? As far as I know every non-ancient drive no longer uses them and you are looking at fake values for compatability with ancient programs. and with 300GB you are really non ancient. 2)  The **reported** sectors migh also be fake if it is a 4K per sector drive and you look at inproperly reported 512b sector reports. In which case the last sector is equal to the last 8 sectors.

Comment: the limit of CHS is 8GB/128GB depending on version, which means it can't address big drives. But why do you care about [CHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector#Heads)? It must be converted to LBA anyway

Comment: @phuclv  I'm writing an MBR

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how do I understand what is happening? I realize that outer cylinders have more sectors/track but I believe that all that information is actually hidden from the end-user and disk controller manages it.

That's right. These days, the C/H/S fields shown in partitioning tools usually contain nonsense, and the only reason you even *see* them in programs at all is because old (MS-DOS era) systems *did* use them and the MBR partition table used to keep sizes in the C/H/S format. Nowadays partitions (even in MBR) are specified and read/write requests made using linear LBA addresses.

Comment: That's exactly why I am asking! I am writing an MBR in assembly. Should I be alright expecting all modern devices to have LBA access? i.e.  `int 0x13 [ax=0x42]` calls to return `cx=0x1`?

Comment: @0fnt: I have no idea about BIOS-driven access (major OSes use direct access instead), but it would be difficult to expect it to be anything but universal by now (e.g. [this MS KB article](https://www.infania.net/ms6kb/Q122052.htm) says that AMI BIOS had it since 1994). That said, _please_ include such details in the question up-front...

Answer (score 0):

Simple, if you take the total amount of sectors, divide it by 255 and by 63, you get 38913 <s>sectors</s> cylinders, as it must be an integer.